# BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring

I've created login application using spring 4.2.5.release. I deployed war (springmvclogin.war) on tomcat 7.0.62 from backend (placed war inside webapps folder of tomcat). When I ran startup.bat, my server started successfully. But during login I got the below exception-

BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via ApplicationContext

As per my understanding, there are two folder created inside webapps- springmvclogin and root. During server startup it initialize beans from both springmvclogin and root. It means application_context.xml is loaded twice and causing the problem. If I'll change my war name to root, It works fine as there will be single folder i.e. root and hence application_context.xml will load only once.

This solution need to modify server configuration but I need solution from spring.
Please let me know the solution.